# featching cat_desc according cat_name from xml

Tags: android, saxparser

I have to display cat_name in listview and when i click any name it will display it's cat_description. my url is http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com/admin/catdata.xml

I can able to display name in listview.My problem is i parse whole cat_desc but i want particular cat_desc according to cat_name.if any one have an idea for this?

I use

```
if(currenttag.equals("Cat_Desc"))
    sitesList.setCat_Desc(String.valueOf(ch,start,length));
```

For set cat_desc. but it will set all cat_desc but i want specific cat_desc.
When i fetching cat_desc i use sitelist.getcatdesc().size().It will show me approximately 4500.

If any one having any solution or give me solution for this.

My Handler-

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException 

{     
   currenttag=localName;

if(currenttag.equals("NewDataSet")) {           
    currentElement =true;       
    sitesList = new SitesList();            

   }            
}
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)throws SAXException

{

    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
        if(qName.equals("NewDataSet"))
          {
            currentElement = false;
          }

     }
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)throws SAXException

{


if(currenttag.equals("Cat_Name"))


   sitesList.setCat_Name(String.valueOf(ch,start,length));



else if(currenttag.equals("Cat_Desc"))


   sitesList.setCat_Desc(String.valueOf(ch,start,length));
```

java class--

```
 for (int i = 0; i less than sitesList.getCat_Name().size(); i++) 

    catNames[i]=sitesList.getCat_Name().get(i);         



for(int j=0; j less than sitesList.getCat_Desc().size();j++)                

   catdesc[j]=sitesList.getCat_Desc().get(j);
```

Thanks and Regards

Arpit

Comment: Show the code that how you are trying, so that we can give you some idea about that.

Comment: I have edited please check it

Comment: I would insist you to use a Map<Key,Value> to store the value and get the value from the selected key on List click.

Comment: have you seen mu url.cat_desc contain html tags and it will store like <,style...,/span,>.... I store it in Arraylist.for getting i use for (int i = 0; i<sitesList.getCat_desc().size(); i++) but it contain whole cat_desc.my problem is how i recognize for particular cat_name.

Comment: YOu are not getting me, I am saying the way you are storing it in arrayList same way store then in map and you can get the value by using the key of the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can modify this code:

```
else if(currenttag.equals("Cat_Desc"))


   sitesList.setCat_Desc(String.valueOf(ch,start,length));
```

To this

```
 else if(currenttag.equals("Cat_Desc")){
   sitesList.setCat_Desc(String.valueOf(ch,start,length));
     if(currentCat.equals("desired_cat"){
       specialDescription = String.valueOf(ch,start,length);
```

Where specialDescription is a field (instance variable) in your SaxParser class.

Comment: hi Kurtis thanks for reply.have you seen url it contain cat_desc field. if i press 1st cat name field it will display cat_desc so it will display 1st cat_desc.in loop second if see cat_desc size it show me above 4500.means it will parse whole cat_desc but i want specific descrition.how can i do this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you on this. Is everything working now?